# ¿cómo saltar inputs en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

para practicar estoy haciendo una calculadora sencilla en python 3 y en mi código tengo guardada una función input en una variable para poder hacer una operación aritmética y esta se muestra como una orden, cosa que yo no hice.
me gustaría saber ¿Por qué pasa? GRACIAS!
E aquí el código.

```
from calculadora import add, sub, div, mult

op = input("Elige la operacion :")
x = input("Ingresa un numero:")
y = input("ingresa un numero:")
n1 = float(x)
n2 = float(y)

if   op == "sumar":
    add(n1,n2)
elif op == "restar":
    sub(n1, n2)
elif op == "dividir":
    div(n1, n2)
else:
    mult(n1,n2)
```

Comment: Cuál es el funcionamiento que esperas que suceda?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que no se ejecuten las instrucciones dentro de las variables " op,x,y"